# Get the link of last successful timer link

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm implementing dynamic trigger for my CI job, i see we can give last successful artifacts

```
job/job_name/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifacts/text_file_that_contains_my_paths
```

But the problem is last successful may not be a mainline one, it might be the one which is not in mainline yet.
is there any keyword to get lastSuccessful timer trigger Build ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I could not understand what kind of jenkins job are you using, how you try to get the artifact and what did you mean with "mainline". Some clarification would be great

Comment: sorry for not making it clear, our setup gets triggerred for gerrits which is older master + some changes , so a gerrit which is not merged yet to master , and 2nd case is same CI gets triggers timely for master latest too, for any releases i have to rely on master trigger, not the gerrit triggers. lastsuccessfulbuild can be a gerrit trigger or master time trigger, i would like to know last succesful time trigger build.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand your setup. How many jobs do you have? Two? And what kind of jenkins jobs are they? Free-jobs? Pipelines? Other?